# Effectively modelling extended classes

Tags: mysql, normalization, relational-theory, orm

I have 3 different types of content for a website, 'Article', 'Video', 'Review'.  Each of those three types of content contain common fields and type specific fields.  For this, I have created the following 5 tables:

```
content - being the primary table containing the common fields across all content types
content_type - name, description, and type specific table name of available content types
article - the table that contains all the type specific fields for content of type 'Article'
video - the table that contains all the type specific fields for content of type 'Video'
review - the table that contains all the type specific fields for content of type 'Review'
```

I am a bit confused as to properly create the relationships between the tables. Realistically one 'content' row relates to one 'article' (type specific table) row.  To me this sounds like a one to one - non-identifying relationship.  Where I am think I am getting most confused, is the type can be one of many. So should they be One to Many or Many to Many, identifying / non-identifying?

I need to be able to search the content fields and then retrieve the corresponding type specific row based on the search.  I also need to be able to search the type specific fields, and retrieve the corresponding content row for search matches.

Also to note, I am using MySQL with Doctrine/ORM, however I am not looking for the SQL statements here I am just looking to better understand what the relationships should actually look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have supertype (content) which may be one of different suptypes (article, video,review). One approach to model such relationship in database is :

```
CONTENT(content_id, content_type_id, PK(content_id), UNIQUE(content_type_id,content_id));

 ARTICLE(content_id, content_type_id, 
  other attributes, 
  PK(content_type_id,content_id), 
  FK(content_type_id,content_id), CHECK (content_type_id = 'article_type_id'));

VIDEO(content_id, content_type_id, 
  other attributes, 
  PK(content_type_id,content_id), 
  FK(content_type_id,content_id), CHECK (content_type_id = 'video_type_id'));
```

etc.

`UNIQUE(content_type_id,content_id)` seems redundant, but it's used to enforce storing of the sub-types in proper table, and only once. CHECK constraint restricts proper content type in each of detail tables. As far as I remember, Mysql still doesn't have <strike>unique</strike> **CHECK** constraints, but you can use `enum` to emulate them.

Comment: I am pretty sure with MySQL you can create UNIQUE keys (if I am reading your answer correctly).  So to be clear then article would have a one to one relationship with content using 'content_type_id' as the foreign key, and video would have a one to one relationship with content using the same 'content_type_id' as the foreign key.  Then 'content_id' and 'content_type_id' would be combined as the primary key (which is unique anyhow?)  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: let me rephrase that a little, above when I used content_type_id, what I really meant was 'content_other_attributes_id'.  'content_type_id' would be used to link the type table with the content table if that makes sense.

Comment: @AaronMurray : yeah, I was thinking about `CHECK` constraints, but somehow typed `unique`. Fixing, thank you

Comment: @AaronMurray: Yeah, content_id + content_type id are PK and FK in detail tables. And `content_id` is unique itself (even without content_type_id).

Comment: Thank you for your help, after drawing, erasing, drawing again, I think I ironed out the logic behind the table relationships.  If I had a way to link an image here I would show you but I think I have it right now.