# Correct way to join row in parent table to row in one of several children tables

Tags: postgresql, join, hierarchy, inheritance

I have a parent table `product`, and several children tables like `phone`, `tablet`, `smartwatch` etc. The parent and children have 1-1 relationship. This means that for every row in parent table, there will be exactly 1 row in exactly one of the several children tables. This is to basically pull up common fields in a single table (like product.product_name), in my effort to follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Now the part where i am worried is that, although i can easily join to the parent row, provided the child row, how would i efficiently do vice versa.
For example: if i have a row from the product table, and now i want to get the rest of the product information, how would i quickly find which child table contains the rest of the information, other than having to check each and every child table in a big query. In simpler words: **How to efficiently find the correct child table in order to join a row in parent table to its corresponding row in one of the children tables.**

Let's assume i would soon have 100+ children tables. In such a case, an exhaustive query would get bigger and bigger with every new child table.

One obvious solution would be to maintain a 'product_type' field in the parent table. But this is clearly redundant information, violates the [Single Source Of Truth rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth) , and prone to human error (eg; product_type says 'phone' but the product actually was a 'tablet'). So i am not sure if this is the recommended way to do it.

I am meaning to find out the canonical way to solving such a problem when designing schema, and not just an opinion-based answer.

I am sorry if this wasn't the right forum to ask this question.

**UPDATE:**

I later came across this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55258/145235) to another post and am really feeling positive about it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your whole schema is not fully thought through.

A product is a product which, presumably, you are going to sell?

Have one product table - no need to split the products up into `phone`, `tablet` or `smartwatch`. There's no problem having millions of records in a table these days.

Have a table `product_category` (or `type` as you suggest) which will have `phone`, `tablet` &c. which will be a `FOREIGN KEY` (pointing back to an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`) in the `product` table. Then you can have your classic `supplier`, `client`, `billing` tables &c.

You might want to take a look at [databaseanswers.org](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) and also you could download Open Source products which correspond to your particular system - check out their schemas and see what they've done.

You asked about the canonical way of designing these sorts of schemas - this is (probably) it. Plus, you won't be writing queries with 100's of tables. You mentioned [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) and [SPOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth). Don't forget [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) (You Ain't Going To Need It) - also espoused by Eric Raymond in the excellent "[The Art of Unix Programming](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/)".

Don't try and be all things to all men from day one! Start easy and design incrementally - don't expect to get everything right the first time (hint: you won't :-)) - best of luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I must mention that keeping just one table would mean leaving a lot of fields empty (smartwatch_band_color field would mean nothing to a phone type row).
But 'Don't try and be all things to all men from day one' is very true!

Comment: You could have a description text field - you didn't tag the question with the RDBMS you are using! You could use JSON if it's PostgreSQL?